# antMatchers that matches any beginning of path

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I've got REST service that will be used for authentication. The authentication endpoint will look like `/api/v.1/authentication`. The API version is a variable that can be changed to reflect updated versions. One example would be `/api/v.2/authentication`. I like to have an `antMatcher` that can deal with both these cases so I tried `.antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"**/authenticate").permitAll()` using `**` to match any beginning of the endpoint but this doesn't work. The full setup below.

```java
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
             .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "**/authenticate").permitAll()
             .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "**/get-public-key").permitAll()
             .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
             .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
             .anyRequest().authenticated();
}
```

Any suggestions how I can solve this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have to use absolute pattern, see [`AntPathMatcher`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/AntPathMatcher.html):

> **Note:** a pattern and a path must both be absolute or must both be relative in order for the two to match. Therefore it is recommended that users of this implementation to sanitize patterns in order to prefix them with "/" as it makes sense in the context in which they're used.

Your modified and simplified configuration:

```java
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/**/authenticate").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/**/get-public-key").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();
}
```