# intercept-url patterns for REST URLs

Tags: rest, spring-security

I am designing a set of REST APIs for accessing the URLs. As per my requirement there are two URLs:

```
http://localhost:3126/securitydemo/webapi/db/students
```

to view all the students no access required and

```
http://localhost:3126/securitydemo/webapi/db/students/1
```

only `ROLE_USER` are allowed.

My Spring Security configuration:

```xml
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="**/students/*" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
    <http-basic/>
</http>
```

If I use the pattern `**/students/*` no basic security popup occurs. If I use `/**` it's working properly.

How can I intercept the two URLs with different security levels?

My REST service class:

```java
@Path("/db")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class StudentService {
    static StudentDao data = new StudentDaoImpl();
    @Path("/students")
    @GET
    public Response getStudents(){
        GenericEntity<List<Student>> entity = new GenericEntity<List<Student>>(data.getAllStudents()){};
        return  Response.ok(entity).build();
    }

    @Path("/students/{id}")
    @GET
    public Response getStudent(@PathParam("id") int id){
        return  Response.ok(data.getStudent(id)).build();
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [antMatchers that matches any beginning of path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43704389/antmatchers-that-matches-any-beginning-of-path)

Comment: You are missing a `/`. Try `/**/students/*`.

Answer (score -2):

try this

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/securitydemo/webapi/db/students/1/**"   access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
        <http-basic/>
    </http>
```

Comment: /Students/1  here 1 is a path variable its not fixed

Comment: You can't do that using spring security try method level annotation @PreAuthorize("permitAll()") and @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")