# authorize request with wildcard preceding url in spring web security

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-security, restful-authentication

I have a rest endpoint of the form

`{pathvariable}/foo/`

and I want to permit access to this url:

```
httpSecurity
     .authorizeRequests()
        // Allow following urls to be called without authentification
        .antMatchers("**/foo").permitAll()
```

What I tried above is not working. Can anybody help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [antMatchers that matches any beginning of path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43704389/antmatchers-that-matches-any-beginning-of-path)

Comment: As you can read in the link in your own answer, it should work, if you use an absolute path not a relative path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found it myself: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/AntPathMatcher.html

.antMatchers("/{pathvariable:[0-9A-Za-z]+}/comment")